# How to add GoLand Go executable to Windows Path?

Tags: bash, go, goland

*I'm just starting with Go, so of course I stumble on errors on every corner. Well not really, it's way better then when I started with Java. But there is one issue.*

I'm using GoLand IDE from JetBrains, and within it's integrated terminal I can easily use `go` command.

```
go version // Output: go version go1.17.5 windows/amd64
```

But when I try the same in GitBash the response is `bash: go: command not found`.

Where to find the executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered that I have the [best File Search application](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) there is for Windows and just typed in `go.exe`.

The file was promptly and obviously found just where I had saved it when starting my first project, that is in `C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\sdk\go1.17.5\bin\` which is exactly what I needed to save in the PATH variable.

So for those who don't know:

- press "Win" key
- type "env"
- select "Edit the system environment variables"
- select "Environment Variables"
- double-click "Path" in the list below "System variables"
- select "New"
- paste the whole path of the directory where you have found `go.exe` in (in my case "C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\sdk\go1.17.5\bin\go.exe" or "%userprofile%\sdk\go1.17.5\bin" for short and exportable)
- click "OK" a few times :)